# How to resolve HTTP-403 Forbidden Spring Boot basic authentication using Postman

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-security

I am fairly new to Spring Boot and Spring Security. Going through various tutorials and lectures, I implemented a small Spring Boot application and now I am trying to secure my endpoints.

I have created a security config which extends `WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter`, which I'm using to secure my application.

```
public class LoginSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter
{

    @Autowired
    public void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder authManager) throws Exception
    {
        authManager
            .inMemoryAuthentication()
            .withUser("carAdmin").password(passwordEncoder().encode("carAdmin123")).roles("CAR_ADMIN")
            .and()
            .withUser("driverAdmin").password(passwordEncoder().encode("driverAdmin123")).roles("DRIVER_ADMIN", "DRIVER")
            .and()
            .withUser("driver").password("driver@123").roles("DRIVER");
    }


    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception
    {

        http
            .csrf().disable().formLogin().disable()
            .headers().frameOptions().disable().and()
            .authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers("/h2-console/**").permitAll()
            .antMatchers("/cars/**").hasAnyRole("CAR_ADMIN")
            .antMatchers("/drivers/**").hasAnyRole("DRIVER_ADMIN", "DRIVER")
            .anyRequest().authenticated();
    }

    @Bean
    public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }
```

And in my RestAPI resource I have used `@PreAuthorize`.

```
@GetMapping("/{carId}")
    @PreAuthorize("hasRole('ROLE_CAR_ADMIN')")
    public CarDTO getCar(@Valid @PathVariable long carId) throws EntityNotFoundException {
        return CarMapper.makeCarDTO(carService.find(carId));
    }
```

I want to test it using Postman.

Also, I also saw online that we can create webpages to implement the authentication but I am looking for very basic authentication. That way, I could use basic auth and Postman to test it.

Currently with this approach I am choosing `basic auth` in Postman, passing the username and password but getting `Forbidden, access denied.`

I don't know what I'm doing wrong or how I can fix it.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try adding `@EnableWebSecurity` to your `LoginSecurityConfig`, and it seems like you haven't enabled basic auth. You can enable it like this:

```
@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

    http
        .csrf().disable().formLogin().disable()
        ...

    http.httpBasic();
}
```

Comment: Hey, it seems to be working but very for the very first time. Means if I pass the first request with incorrect, i am not able to access. But if I am passing the first request with correct credentials and for the second request if the credentials are wrong, i am still able to access for 2nd request.. is that expected ?

Comment: Check out the source code for BasicAuthenticationFilter. You'll see that it only re-authenticates if " username doesn't match SecurityContextHolder and user isn't authenticated". I'm guessing the 2nd time, you only change the password, not the username. Since the Authentication is saved in the session, and so you're already authenticated the 2nd time, the request will pass.